# Get text in a list then split it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of tag like this

```
    <ul class="tagList">

        <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">example4</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Now i want to get the text inside it, then split everytext like this

```
example1 example2 example3 example4
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can first create array and then `join(' ')` to string with spaces.

```js
var text = $('ul li a').map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
}).get().join(' ')

console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tagList">
  <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create separate file for css and paste this code:
        .tagList,li{
          display: inline;
        }

Now open html file and paste below lines:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/style.css">
        <title> My home page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul class="tagList">

         <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">example4</a></li>

     </ul>
      </body>
    </html>

you can create separate CSS file or you can add within html file, depends on you. Hope you got me.
```